# How to get collision detection to work between rectangles?

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, collision-detection

My code is not getting any errors, however it is not behaving as I expect it to.

The problem is here:

```
if bomb_rect.colliderect(pacman_rect)==True:
    print("hello")
```

The `print("hello")` should only execute if the two rectangles collide, however it executes every time no matter what.  I'm not sure what I've overlooked.

Edit:
Sorry for the confusion. My apologies, let me explain it again, I have two pictures imported, one is a bomb, one is Pacman. When the two pictures collide, "hello" will be printed. The source of error is not bomb_rect.colliderect(pacman_rect) rather it is where the image is set. The coordinates for the bomb is set random. and Pacman will appear at (0,0). However when I move the Pacman around, I find that even though that the bomb image is set elsewhere, there is still a invisible bomb image set at (0,0). Because when I move Pacman image further than (0,0), "hello" stops printing.

```
import pygame,sys,random
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
blue=(0,250,0)
red=(255,0,0)
black=(0,0,0)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1080, 720))

bomb=pygame.image.load("bomb2.bmp")
bomb_rect = bomb.get_rect()

pacman=pygame.image.load("pacman.png")
pacman_rect = pacman.get_rect()

pygame.display.set_caption('game')
background=pygame.Surface(screen.get_size()).convert()
background.fill((255,255,255))



randBombX = random.randrange(0,screen.get_width()-200)
randBombY = random.randrange(0,screen.get_height()-200)
bomb_rect.move(randBombX ,randBombY)


dir_x = 0
dir_y = 0
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
moving=True
while moving:

    clock.tick(20)
    screen.blit(background, (0,0))

    pacman_rect.move_ip(dir_x, dir_y)
    screen.blit(pacman, pacman_rect)
    screen.blit(bomb,(randBombX ,randBombY))
    pygame.display.flip()

    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
            quit()
        if e.type == KEYDOWN:
            if e.key == K_ESCAPE:
                moving = False
                quit()
            if e.key == K_LEFT:
                if dir_x ==0 and dir_x >=0:
                    dir_x-=10
                if dir_x == 10:
                    dir_x-=20
                dir_y=0
            if e.key == K_RIGHT:
                if dir_x == 0 and dir_x <=0:
                    dir_x+=10
                if dir_x == -10:
                    dir_x+=20
                dir_y=0
            if e.key == K_UP:
                if dir_y ==0 and dir_y <=0:
                    dir_y -=10
                if dir_y == 10:
                    dir_y -=20
                dir_x=0
            elif e.key == K_DOWN:
                if dir_y ==0 and dir_y >=0:
                    dir_y +=10
                if dir_y == -10:
                    dir_y +=20
                dir_x=0


    if pacman_rect.left < 0 or pacman_rect.right >= screen.get_width():
        dir_x *= -1
    if pacman_rect.top < 0 or pacman_rect.bottom >= screen.get_height():
        dir_y *= -1
    if bomb_rect.colliderect(pacman_rect)==True:
        print("hello")
```

Comment: codeReview material, not really stackOverflow. Try checking whether your checks work. That might be a case for unit tests.

Comment: @MarcusMüller No, it's not [codereview.se] material.  This code does not work as intended and code that does not work as intended is explicitly off-topic on [codereview.se].  In fact, while this may or may not be a good question, it's **well** within the scope of [so].  The user's code isn't working as intended and is asking for assistance fixing it.  If this isn't on-topic for [so], I don't know what is.

Comment: @nhgrif Good point; Michael, please accept my apologies. However, I still think it's not clear what you're asking, because you don't explain what you've tried to do to pin down where things go wrong; if you could do that and come up with the problems you've encountered, I think you'd give us a question that is far better to answer.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I've edited his question--I think it's more clear now what is being asked.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. My apologies, let me explain it again, I have two pictures imported, one is a bomb, one is pacman. When the two pictures collide, "hello" will be printed.  The source of error is not   bomb_rect.colliderect(pacman_rect)  rather it is where the image is set. The coordinates for the bomb is set random. and Pacman will appear at (0,0). However when I move the pacman around, I find that even though that the bomb image is set elsewhere, there is still a invisible bomb image set at (0,0). Becasue when i move pacman image further than (0,0), "hello" stops printing.

Comment: Please **edit** your question and say what you just wrote here in the question. In the meantime, I'll just delete three fourths of my answer :/.

Answer (score 0):

```
if bomb_rect.colliderect(pacman_rect)==True:
```

is a bit redundant; `a == True` is the same as `a` for boolean values (if `a` is `True`, `a==True` is `True`; otherwise, it's `False`). But that shouldn't change the behaviour of your program.

But:

```
            if dir_x ==0 and dir_x >=0:
                dir_x-=10
```

Just happens if `dir_x == 0` (maybe you're confusing `and` and `or`? Either way, one of the conditions is included in the other). You have more of these `if`s in your code; I'm not quite sure what they should have been doing, but as far as I can tell, that might alter the behavior of your game from what you're expecting.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, It should be `or`.  I also do have a ton of if statements, i will try to fix that.
I think the problem is `bomb_rect.move(randBombX,randBombY)` here, i am not sure if the image is set randomly.